# how to get value from array of object on basis of other parameter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, servicenow

consider the below array having objects and that object also have array. what I am looking for is, if I pass  'Australia/Melbourne' to below array the output should be 'AUS Eastern Standard Time' i.e value element of second object(as second object contain value 'AUS Eastern Standard Time' in 'utc' array.)

Note I have tried `var winTimeZone = arr.find(tz => tz.utc && tz.utc.includes('Australia/Melbourne));`

Servicenow platform doesn't support find method. Please shar any other solution. Thanks

```
var arr =[
    {
        "isdst": false,
        "offset": "09:30:00",
        "text": "(UTC+09:30) Darwin",
        "utc": [
            "Australia/North",
            "Australia/Darwin"
        ],
        "value": "AUS Central Standard Time"
    },

    {
        "isdst": true,
        "offset": "10:00:00",
        "text": "(UTC+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney",
        "utc": [
            "Australia/Sydney",
            "Australia/Melbourne",
            "Australia/Hobart",
            "Australia/Victoria",
            "Australia/ACT",
            "Australia/Canberra",
            "Australia/NSW",
            "Australia/Tasmania",
            "Australia/Currie"
        ],
        "value": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
    }]
```

Comment: If the platform doesn't support `find`, then use a simple loop, like the one shown in the [`find` polyfill on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, could you please post some code here related to my scenario

Answer (score 0):

I think your code was not working, anyway. It is the first time I hear that the Platform teams disallowing such a fundamental feature of javascript. My best recommendation is to change company.

Try this:

```js
var arr =[
    {
        "isdst": false,
        "offset": "09:30:00",
        "text": "(UTC+09:30) Darwin",
        "utc": [
            "Australia/North",
            "Australia/Darwin"
        ],
        "value": "AUS Central Standard Time"
    },

    {
        "isdst": true,
        "offset": "10:00:00",
        "text": "(UTC+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney",
        "utc": [
            "Australia/Sydney",
            "Australia/Melbourne",
            "Australia/Hobart",
            "Australia/Victoria",
            "Australia/ACT",
            "Australia/Canberra",
            "Australia/NSW",
            "Australia/Tasmania",
            "Australia/Currie"
        ],
        "value": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
    }]
    
    const utcValueForCity = (utcCity) => 
      arr.reduce((acum, current)=>
        acum || (current.utc.includes(utcCity)?current.value:undefined)
    , undefined)
    
    console.log(utcValueForCity("Australia/Melbourne"))
```

Comment: @Avinash Can you check if this is the right answer so other people can learn from your question? Help community...

Answer (score 0):

This code uses older syntax that will almost certainly be supported:

```js
var arr = [
  {
    "isdst": false,
    "offset": "09:30:00",
    "text": "(UTC+09:30) Darwin",
    "utc": [
      "Australia/North",
      "Australia/Darwin"
    ],
    "value": "AUS Central Standard Time"
  },
  {
    "isdst": true,
    "offset": "10:00:00",
    "text": "(UTC+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney",
    "utc": [
      "Australia/Sydney",
      "Australia/Melbourne",
      "Australia/Hobart",
      "Australia/Victoria",
      "Australia/ACT",
      "Australia/Canberra",
      "Australia/NSW",
      "Australia/Tasmania",
      "Australia/Currie"
    ],
    "value": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
  }
];

var winTimeZone;
for (var dataInd = 0; dataInd < arr.length; dataInd++) {
  var tz = arr[dataInd];
  for (var locationsInd = 0; locationsInd < tz.utc.length; locationsInd++) {
    if (tz.utc.indexOf("Australia/Melbourne") > -1) {
      winTimeZone = tz.value;
    }
  }
}
console.log("winTimeZone: " + winTimeZone);
```